# using XOR to create a checkbyte

Tags: c

I've been tasked with working out some scanty instructions in regards to working out a checkbyte from a byte sequence between a cash register and a scale, and then implement it in C.

Instructions from the manual (to get the checkbyte):

```
ID XOR B1 XOR B2 XOR B3 XOR B4 XOR B5
```

Other similar protocols mention that it might be `XORing` the most significant bit in each byte - (I've no idea how to do that, or even if its required)

Luckily I have the scale and a computer to check exactly what is being sent, the `ID = ascii`i and `B1 to B5` is the weight, in this example, when the weight on the scale shows 00748; The sequence returned in `ascii is`i00748 then the checkbyte is sent: `45 decimal.`

Some code I tried below unfortunately **returns 82 in decimal.**

```
    char out = 0;
    char in[6] = "i00748";
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        out = out ^ in[i];

    printf("%d",out);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems most likely that they meant to xor the whole byte, and your code is correct.

Comment: if it is XORing the most significant bit in each byte, how would I go about doing that do u think?

Comment: Then the answer would be 0, as all of these bytes have MSB 0

Comment: Note that the algorithm shown is very weak; you can reorder the digits (and letter) in the string and still end up with the same answer.  Are you sure that's what the docs say?  Do they show an example?

Comment: 45 decimal is `0x7F` XOR'd with your result, does that trigger any bells for you?  (i.e. toggle all bits except for the MSB)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler cash registers often use [LRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_redundancy_check) which is indeed weak, it's supposed to be a very computationally-simple way of detecting a flipped bit on the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol is using 7-bit ASCII with odd parity for each bit. Which is to say that the MSB of every byte (including the check byte) is 0. And each bit in the check byte is a 0 if there's an odd number of 1's at that bit position, 1 otherwise.

To illustrate, here's the message shown in binary

```
01101001   i   ID
00110000   0   B1
00110000   0   B2
00110111   7   B3
00110100   4   B4
00111000   8   B5
--------
00101101   -   check byte
```

Note that in each column, if the message bytes contain an even number of 1's, then the check byte also has a 1, but if the message bytes contain an odd number of ones, then the check byte has a 0. The exception is the MSB, which is 0 for all the message bytes and the check byte.

So all you need to do to fix your code is start with

```
out = 0x7f;
```

Comment: Good spotting. It could equally well be using even parity in the protocol. OP's example has 3 numbers with an odd number of bits set, and 3 with an even number of bits set, so XORing all of the bytes as received from the cash register with `0xFF` would give the right result.

Comment: hmm the scale itself is set to 7N1, checked it with other values, it works! THANKYOU, so i see that 0x7F is 128 dec, but can't figure out the significance, any literature out there on whats going on?

Comment: @user975033 0x7f is actually 127 decimal, or `01111111` binary. In other words, starting with 0x7f flips all the bits in the result, but leaves the MSB untouched.